# Fix table vertical centering in WordPress pages

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, themes

Most WordPress themes (including MH lite) bring in CSS or something that messes up the vertical centering in tables. Tortuga Lite is an exception, but I do not like that theme.

I need to know how I can override whatever the themes are doing.

An iframe would work if I included the CSS, but I think it will mess up the Google indexing.

I think if I knew the right CSS, I could include it in the head of all pages using the per-page-add-to-head widget.

I tried tr {vertical-align: middle;} in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` in line 17 of style.css is set to `baseline`.

If you set it to `vertical-align: inherit` under `.auto-style2` in TestPageOnly.css, it'll override the baseline alignment and give you vertical centering.

Comment: Thanks.  I also found that adding img {vertical-align: middle !important;} in the site-wide CSS solves the problem across the whole site.

Comment: That's true - just be careful using `!important`, since it overrides any other existing CSS selectors and can quickly get messy. For example, if you needed to override `vertical-align` elsewhere on the site, it'll be a pain to do so with an `!important` in place.